# What are these needle-like plants growing in the ground?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I was outside and noticed some strange, needle-like plants growing on the ground. I managed to search for "needlegrass" but couldn't find it.

Here is the photo taken on April 20, 2021 in Long Beach, California; these red circles point at what the strange plants look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a [Filaree](http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/WEEDS/filarees.html)/heron's bill/stork's bill (*Erodium* species). These are widespread in California, being plants of disturbed and unmanaged soils - farms, dunes, roadsides, etc.

Note that I'm not Californian, or even from North America, all I did was google "weed species california" (without the quotes) and hit the first link that looked reputable, then used a small bit of knowledge of plant forms (rosette in this case...) to follow the links inside - and found the species at the link I supplied.